# System.in.read() is not returning exact value inside static block

Tags: java

As static block is used to initialize static data member in dynamic way, I have this code:

```
class Temp {
    static int x;

    static {
        try {
            x = System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
}

class Temp1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Temp.x);
    }
}

class Temp2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Temp.x);
    }
}
```

While running Temp1, Temp2 the normal value of x should be what I entered from keyboard, but I got 49 and 50 always no matter whatever I entered from keyboard.

I already see the read() method of inputstream class it should return the same. Why it is returning 49 and 50 in every case?

Comment: `p.s.v.m(String a[])` seriously? you can't be bothered to write the right syntax

Comment: what does p.s.v.m mean? Is it an acronym? Because you can't use full stops

Comment: @BubbaWoop `public static void main`

Comment: you can do that? that's awesome :o

Comment: @BubbaWoop No you can't - it is not valid Java syntax. Some IDEs, like Netbeans for example, use it as a shortcut: you type psvm and the IDE replaces it with `public static void main`.

Comment: @assylias ah makes sense then. Never seen it before, I mainly stick with Eclipse

Comment: @Arun. How can you run two `public static void main` at the same time??

Comment: @BubbaWoop In eclipse, write `main` and then control+space.. There are many other shortcuts.. `sysout` for `System.out.println()`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct question you are asking is not really the first thing that you should be informed of here because the very approach you are taking is quite misguided:

1. Never use class initializers to read from keyboard. There is simply never a good reason to do this.
2. Don't swallow exceptions: you are shooting yourself in the foot. If there is an error, you won't be able to diagnose.
3. You probably expect to **parse an integer** input at keyboard; you are actually only reading a single byte from the standard input (`System.in` is a *byte stream*) and storing it as an `int`.
4. You have two identical classes, with two identical `main` methods in them. This makes no sense: nothing will be "done twice" in any sort of meaning with that code.

This list is by no means exhaustive, it's just what I managed to think of right now.

To conclude, you should redesign your code in the first place just to make the basic approach sane, and only then try to make it work.

Comment: I approve and ask @Arun: what's your intention? Learn Java? Se the Java tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are confused with java types and how does input stream work. 
Method `read()` of input stream reads the next byte and returns it. Byte is not text or string. If for example you type `1` it returns 49 - the ASCII code of character `1`. Typing of character `2` causes it to return 50 etc.

If you type as many character as you want method `read()` will still return the ASCII code of the first character. I think that this is the reason for this "strange" from your point of view behavior.

You probably should wrap input stream into `BufferedInputStream` and then use `readLine()` method, i.e.

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
String s = bis.readLine();
```

Comment: Thank you so much AlexR but I am confuse this why this is returning only ASCII value of first digit..

Comment: For future readers:  BufferedInputStream doesn't have a readLine() method.  Probably meant BufferedReader instead (although the Console class also has one).